# JavaScript Underscore _.each: Why does the order of a callback's arguments matter when referencing object/array properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

When implementing a callback on an array, for example in underscore's _.each method, *why does the order of the callback's arguments matter when accessing either an array or an object's properties*? For example:

```
_.each([1,2,3,4,5], function(item, index, arr) { 
  console.log(item + ', ' + index + ', ' + arr);
});
//output: 1, 0, [1,2,3,4,5];
//output: 2, 1, [1,2,3,4,5];
//output: 3, 2, [1,2,3,4,5];
//etc. until output: 5, 4, [1,2,3,4,5];
```

or

```
_.each({key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}, function(value, key, obj){
  console.log(value + ', ' + key + ', ' + obj)
});
//output: 1, key1, [object Object]
//output: 2, key2, [object Object]
//output: 3, key3, [object Object]
```

Why does the output appear as demonstrated above? Is there a rule somewhere that states the first argument to a callback references a object's value, the second argument references an object's key or index, and the third argument references the object itself?

Comment: [parameters to `Array.prototype.forEach`'s callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)

Comment: Yes. Only then it will be consistent with the JavaScript's native `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: thanks a million thefourtheye :)

Comment: There's a rule, but it's not unwritten.

Comment: awesome. thanks torazaburo--edited question to avoid misleading readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link helps! I also found a more precise answer as I was searching around more just now:

underbar defines _.each as:

```
function _.each(collection, callback){
 if(Array.isArray(collection)){
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    callback(collection[i], i , collection);
  }
 } 
 else {
  for(var key in collection){
    callback(collection[key], key, collection);
  }
 }
}
```

I see that  _.each DOES define the callback's arguments inside the two for loops within its if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

that's just how ecmascript spec defines it to work

ECMAScript spec for forEach :

> callbackfn is called with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the object being traversed.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18

Answer (score 0):

Values can be strings...values can be numbers...keys can be strings or numbers...Values can be Objects...the collection referenced can be an Object...Arrays can have other arrays as values, they can have Objects as values...they can have strings as values that might be the same as a key for some Object...Objects can have other Objects as values...they can have Arrays as values...or strings that are the same as another key on the same object...etc etc etc.

**How would you know what is what if you didn't know that the first param represented one specific thing, the second param another specific thing, the third one the other?**

So when the function is made it's defined which parameter will be which thing by the way it calls the callback. They have to be in some order...and they chose that order. Likely because it matches how the native `.forEach` works.

---

You might be confused about the naming of those parameters, thinking that the name can somehow play a role...e.g. naming the parameter "value" should receive the "value" and therefore what does it matter whether the first or second one is the one named "value"?

That is not how it works. You can name the parameter any valid variable name...it really doesn't affect what it does. There is no predefined way you have to name parameters to get certain things...if there was it would really limit the capabilities of a language. I could name that parameter "flyingSpaghettiMonster" but that won't make it one...that's just the name I'll have to reference each time I want to use that param.